# how to get concatenated values tgt in informatica?

Tags: informatica, scenarios

I have 2 tables
one--src
I have 2 cols,

```
id        Name
101,102   abc,cde
```

---

two--tgt

```
id     Name
101    abc
102    cde
```

How to achieve this in informatica?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you always have one source and two targets like you described, and data will be always like you mentioned.

After source qualifier, you can use and expression tansformation to create below output ports.

```
idcol1 = substr(id, 1, instr(id,',',1))  -- pick up 101 from the concatenated id col
idcol2 = substr(id, instr(id,',',1)+1) -- pick up 102 from the concatenated id col
namecol1 = substr(name, 1, instr(name,',',1))
namecol2 = substr(name, instr(name,',',1)+1)
```

Then use a router with below conditions

```
group1= idcol1= 101
group2= idcol2= 102
```

Then use two sorters after the router. Then attach all the rows to each targets.

```
router_group1 --> linked to Target1
router_group2 --> linked to Target2
```